# Insert CSV Blob Data via SQL

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I'm trying to explore different methods for inserting very large (10 million rows) CSV-Data from a File into the SAP HANA Database (version 1.12).

We've tried many things so far (some more successful then others) and right now I'm stuck at the following:

Managing the data in javascripts has its problems (as in the js-engine freezes) and right now I've managed to upload and insert it with the blob datatype. I know of the 'IMPORT FROM CSV FILE' SQL-function in SAP Hana and I was wondering it is possible to use it with the blob saved in our database.

Thanks in advance for your time & help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, importing BLOB data types is possible with CSV import.
The relevant column needs to be represented as hex-coded binary data enclosed in quotation marks (`"<hex data goes here>"`).